# Uma função que imprima dinamicamente todos os elementos da lista na ordem inversa [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89],

Tags: dart

UMA FUNCÃO EM DART PARA IMPRIMIR OS ELEMENTO NA ORDEM INVERSA
NO CASO ELA ESTARIA ASSIM 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 ESTOU QUERENDO QUE FIQUE ASSIM
89,55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1 REVERSO

Comment: Opa tudo bem? Parece que você é novo por aqui, da uma olhadinha nesses tópicos [Pergunta sem muita qualiade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Pelo seu nome de usuário acredito que já conheça o [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/), correto? Sabia que lá existe alguns atalhos no editor? Por exemplo, crie uma propriedade da seguinte forma `List<int> lista = [1, 2, 3];`, depois na linha de baixo digite `lista.` e com o cursor na frente do "ponto" aperte CTRL+Espaço... Você verá todos os métodos úteis que tal tipo lhe dispõe, com isso você encontrará o que quer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A intrução `for` serve para repetir processos até que a variável declarada chegue ao limite declarado.

```
void main() {
    List<int> lista = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89];

    for (int i = lista.length; i > 0; i--) {
        print(lista[i - 1]);
    }

}

// Saída: 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1
```

Veja que iniciamos a variável `i` com o valor da quantidades de elementos que o vetor `lista` possui (`i = lista.lenght`);

A seguir, definimos até quando o `for` repetirá, no caso ele repetirá enquanto `i` for maior que 0 (`i > 0`);

E, por último, definimos que a cada repetição do `for`, o valor de `i` se subtrai em um (`i--`ou `i = i - 1`).

O mesmo princípio pode ser usado para aumentar, porém se inverte os valores:

```
void main() {
    List<int> lista = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89];
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        print(lista[i]);
    }
}

// Saída: 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

Comment: A sua reposta é legal, mas já existe uma função própria para isso nos tipos `List<T>` que em uma linha você resolve o problema de inverter uma lista.

Comment: O problema é que na questão não é mencionado, mas isso parece ser uma questão acadêmica, e caso esteja começando em Dart é bom pegar os princípios básicos dos laços de repetição também

Comment: A questão é que o AP não nos deu nenhum exemplo do que já tentou até agora e jogou uma "pergunta" genérica e de qualquer jeito, que como você disse "Parece uma questão acadêmica" e provavelmente é, pois existe outra pergunta idêntica dele que foi fechado por não atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade do site . Aconselho que você leia [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/87785).

Comment: Obrigado @JeanFranz pela dica.. na verdade eu estou tendo meus primeiros contatos com Dart, eu entrei nessa plataforma recentemente, em busca de ajuda, até peço desculpa por não ter elaborado uma pergunta melhor.. estou aprendendo ainda usar essa plataforma!! e confesso que já recebi muitos comentários abusivos aqui.. pensava que esse site era para aluno tbm, mais pelo visto só tem doutores.. agradeço por responder minha pergunta deu certo ...